# AS3: How can I define boundaries for a drag-able object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm making an image revealer in flash, but I can't wrap my head around how to constrain the slider bar to the `area_mc`. Mainly in the `mouseMoveHandler`. Can someone please give me some pointers?

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

function init():void  {
    area_mc.sliderbar_mc.buttonMode = true;
    area_mc.sliderbar_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,moveSliderbar);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopSliderbar);
    area_mc.mask_mc.alpha = 0;
    area_mc.after_mc.mask = area_mc.mask_mc;
    TweenLite.to(area_mc.sliderbar_mc,3,{x:stage.stageWidth/2,ease:Elastic.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(area_mc.mask_mc,3,{x:stage.stageWidth/2,ease:Elastic.easeOut});
}  

function moveSliderbar(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoveHandler);
}  

function stopSliderbar(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    area_mc.sliderbar_mc.x = area_mc.mouseX;
    var left:Number = area_mc.x - (area_mc.width / 2);
    var right:Number = area_mc.x + (area_mc.width / 2);

    if (area_mc.sliderbar_mc.x > right) {
        area_mc.sliderbar_mc.x = right;
    }
    else if(area_mc.sliderbar_mc.x < left){
        area_mc.sliderbar_mc.x = left;
    }
    area_mc.mask_mc.x = area_mc.sliderbar_mc.x;
}

init();
```

Comment: I'm extremely confused.. The title of your question and the question itself don't seem to be related?

Comment: Oh sorry if it did. I meant to ask how to contrain the "sliderbar_mc" within "area_mc" when it gets dragged around. Because right now it goes beyond the left and right of area_mc. Hope that clears it up?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to drag a movieclip around and have another movieclip act as though it's attached to it?

Comment: Hi Marty, haha sorry for the confusion. Basically on the stage, I have sliderbar_mc in the middle of area_mc. The sliderbar acts as a 'revealer', so as it's dragged left and right, it reveals a before and after image. The sliderbar should be bound within area_mc. However, right now when I drag sliderbar left and right, it goes beyond the area_mc. Does this make a bit more sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on me interpreting your question as: "how can I give a drag-able item boundaries?".

`startDrag()` has a parameter that accepts a `Rectangle` (`flash.geom.Rectangle`) which will act as a boundary for where you can drag something.

eg.

```
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
startDrag(false, rect);
```

Here's how I would do an object that you drag and limit:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class DragableItem extends MovieClip
    {
        // vars
        private var _boundaries:Rectangle;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function DragableItem()
        {
            // define boundaries
            // left, top, right, bottom
            _boundaries = new Rectangle(30,30,200,200);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _mouseDown);
        }

        /**
         * MOUSE_DOWN
         */
        private function _mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            startDrag(false, _boundaries);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _stopDrag);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, _stopDrag);
        }

        /**
         * MOUSE_UP
         */
        private function _stopDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stopDrag();

            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _stopDrag);
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, _stopDrag);
        }
    }
}
```

Quick test:

```
var drg:DragableItem = new DragableItem();

drg.graphics.beginFill(0);
drg.graphics.drawRect(0,0,60,60);
drg.graphics.endFill();

addChild(drg);
```