# How to stop drag x in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

How to lock / stop drag .x? please help me. i want to make look like a scroll.

```
  sc_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_ClickToDrag_2);


    function fl_ClickToDrag_2(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        sc_btn.startDrag();
    }
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_2);

    function fl_ReleaseToDrop_2(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        sc_btn.stopDrag();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040298/as3-how-can-i-define-boundaries-for-a-drag-able-object

Comment: thanks yo for suggestion bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`startDrag()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) accepts a [`Rectangle`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html) as its second argument, which you can set to be 1 pixel wide.

> Parameters
>
> lockCenter:Boolean (default = false) — Specifies whether the draggable sprite is locked to the center of the pointer position (true), or locked to the point where the user first clicked the sprite (false).
>
> **bounds:Rectangle** (default = null) — Value relative to the coordinates of the Sprite's parent that specify a constraint rectangle for the Sprite.

---

Response to comment:

You can change your code to this:

```
sc_btn.startDrag(false, new Rectange(0, -1000, 1, 2000));
```

Comment: grate but give me some example.